# How to store images for mobile development

Tags: amazon-s3, mobile-development, back4app

I decided to use `back4app` for easily creating my backend and for having a built in hosting solution.

I'm quite a newbie with this tool so my question will seem "simple":

I was wondering how will I store the images of my mobile application. As far as I know they use `AWS` so I thought the service would provide like an interface to upload some images to a S3 bucket...

Should I create a personal bucket or does the service offer that kind of feature ?

The idea is to store then the absolute url of the image in my model. For example each `Class` has a `cover` field of type `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're right, Back4App use AWS. 
Back4App prepared the Backend for you, for example, if you try to save a file direct at your Parse Dashboard, you will can access the image and you already have a absolute URL.You can configure the column with a type File, like below:

[Add a column with the File type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VjcJ.png)

After upload a file, you will can access click at the box :)

[After that upload the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCWY6.png)

Comment: thanks for your answer and do you know how to handle it in Swift ? I mean once you fetch your object is there a way to manage the file (in my case an image)

Comment: Hi! You're welcome. I don't know how :( 
Parse Server offer a Docs to a lot of plataforms, and iOS have this guide: docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#retrieving-objects about retrieving objects using swift. 
Probably, the link below will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578120/how-to-retrieve-a-image-from-parse